# Universal scope and importing variables from one file to another

Tags: go, import, scope

I am new at Go. I am learning about universal scope and importing variables from one file to another.

**Conditions:**

System: [Windows 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_11) x64 
IDE: [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) 
Language: [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28programming_language%29)

According to the universal scope, I should be able to import variables from one file to another easily. Primary file: "main.go" and secondary file ""uniscope.go

Importing from uniscope.go into main.go

If the files are kept in the same folder directory then I can easily import using command: "go run main.go uniscope.go"
This runs without any error, but until this command I get the error in main.go, "undeclared name", that is still not the main issue.

When I move the uniscope.go to another folder and then I run "go run main.go uniscope.go", it doesn't work, which is understandable as directory has been changed. So then I copy the path and paste it in import which in turns resolves the previous error, change the command to "go run main.go" but it throws out a new one.

"main.go:6:7: illegal character U+0073 's' in escape sequence"

I am not sure how I am wrong here. The video I am learning from is: *[Go packages & scope explained!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYD9XWi_Xw8&list=PLve39GJ2D71xX0Ham0WoPaYfl8oTzZfN6&index=5)*

He is using [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA), but I don't think that should be an issue.

I have tried the mentioned above and also tried finding the exact error on Google. I just found a similar question posted on some Portuguese forum without any answers.

Comment: Instead of the video, whatever its content, you should start by taking the [Go Tour](https://go.dev/tour/basics/1), after you've taken it *several* times and you've got the basics down, next you should read this: https://go.dev/doc/code.

Comment: Start by not doing dangerous thing and stop using go run with file name arguments. Try learning from go.dev. (Don't try to learn from random, potentially outdated, low quality videos.)

Answer (score 0):

`main.go`:

```
package main

import "hello/world"

func main() {
   println(world.Value)
}
```

`world/world.go`:

```
package world

const Value = 1
```

and run:

```
go mod init hello
go run .
```